# BibLaTeX style "philosophy-verbose" with "shorthandintro=false" option gives keyval Error

Tags: biblatex

I am using biblatex and philosophy-verbose style to insert references in my LaTeX document. In some bib entries, I have inserted a shorthand field and decided to cite them only with the shorthand as label from beginning to end. But I get a Package keyval Error when using the philosophy-verbose style with the shorthandintro=false option. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=philosophy-verbose,backend=biber,language=auto, shorthandintro=false]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@Book{A1,
  Title                    = {Title1},
  Author                   = {AuthorA},
  Year                     = {1900},
  Shorthand                = {GuI}
}

@Book{B2,
  Title                    = {Title2},
  Author                   = {AuthorB},
  Year                     = {1900}
}

@Book{C2,
  Title                    = {Title2},
  Author                   = {AuthorC},
  Year                     = {1900}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}


"Some citation of a shorthand title"\footcite[][34]{A1}

"Some citation of the same title from another page"\footcite[][70]{A1}

"Some citation of a non-shorthand title"\footcite[][12]{B2}

"Some citation of the same non-shorthand title from another page"\footcite[][15]{B2}

"Some citation of the same non-shorthand title from another author"\footcite[][15]{C2}

\printshorthands

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Is there someting I'm doing wrong or is it a bug in the philosophy-verbose style?

Maybe there is a workaround as described in [How can I use shorthands in citations from the first time with biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73913/how-can-i-use-shorthands-in-citations-from-the-first-time-with-biblatex) . But the solution is only working for "verbose" style, but I would need to use "verbose-trad2", if philosophy-verbose would indeed be buggy.

Comment: It's not a bug. The style `philosophy-verbose` is not based on `philosophy-classic` where the option `shorthandintro` is defined.

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will read the starter guide. As for your answer: The option `shorthandintro` can be found in the `"User's Guide to biblatex philosophy"` under `"8.1 Global Options"` and not under `"8.2 Style-specific options"`, so I figured it could be applied to `philosophy-verbose` too. As this seems not to be the case, maybe I should write an e-mail to Ivan Valbusa, because it seems misleading to me mentioning `shorthandintro` option in the Global options chapter?

Comment: Indeed the documentation is misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style `philosophy-verbose` is not based on `philosophy-classic` where the option `shorthandintro` is defined, so you can not use it.

Adding this re-definition in the preamble seems, however, to do what you want

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx:fullcite}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \bibhypertarget{cite\the\value{instcount}}{%
    \ifciteseen
      {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
         {\ifciteibid
            {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
            {\ifthenelse{\ifciteidem\AND\NOT\boolean{cbx:noidem}}
               {\usebibmacro{cite:idem}}
               {\usebibmacro{cite:name}}%
             \usebibmacro{cite:title}}%
      \usebibmacro{cite:save}}
         {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
      {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:full}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:save}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=philosophy-verbose,backend=biber,language=auto]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx:fullcite}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \bibhypertarget{cite\the\value{instcount}}{%
    \ifciteseen
      {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
         {\ifciteibid
            {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
            {\ifthenelse{\ifciteidem\AND\NOT\boolean{cbx:noidem}}
               {\usebibmacro{cite:idem}}
               {\usebibmacro{cite:name}}%
             \usebibmacro{cite:title}}%
      \usebibmacro{cite:save}}
         {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
      {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:full}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:save}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@Book{A1,
  Title                    = {Title1},
  Author                   = {AuthorA},
  Year                     = {1900},
  Shorthand                = {GuI}
}

@Book{B2,
  Title                    = {Title2},
  Author                   = {AuthorB},
  Year                     = {1900}
}

@Book{C2,
  Title                    = {Title2},
  Author                   = {AuthorC},
  Year                     = {1900}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}


"Some citation of a shorthand title"\footcite[][34]{A1}

"Some citation of the same title from another page"\footcite[][70]{A1}

"Some citation of a non-shorthand title"\footcite[][12]{B2}

"Some citation of the same non-shorthand title from another page"\footcite[][15]{B2}

"Some citation of the same non-shorthand title from another author"\footcite[][15]{C2}

\printshorthands

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is indeed, what I was looking for. Thank you very much! As far as I can tell by now, this does exactly, what I desire.

Comment: @Wamseln Happy about that!