# How do I use shorthand from the first time with verbose-trad1

Tags: biblatex, shorthands

I am using `biblatex`, Biber, and `style=verbose-trad1` for my LaTeX document. However, I would like, not to print the full title the first time, when using shorthands, but to have the shorthand abbreviation appear also the first time in the footnote.

This has been solved for `verbose` [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73913/how-can-i-use-shorthands-in-citations-from-the-first-time-with-biblatex) already, but does not work when changing style to `verbose-trad1`.

So I would like it to say only

> KpV

instead of

> Kant 1968 (henceforth cited as KpV)

the first time it appears.

Any idea how to solve this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=verbose-trad1]{biblatex}

% Original definition
% \newbibmacro*{cite}{%
%   \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
%   \ifciteseen
%     {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
%        {\usebibmacro{cite:short}}
%        {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
%     {\usebibmacro{cite:full}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifciteseen
       {\usebibmacro{cite:short}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:full}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{Kan68,
  shorthand = {KpV},
  author = {Kant, Immanuel},
  year = {1968},
  title = {Kritik der praktischen Vernunft},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\null\vfill% just for the example

Some text.\autocite{Kan68}

Some text.\autocite{Kan68}

Some text.\autocite{A01}

Some text.\autocite{A01}

\printshorthands

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this redefinition

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \bibhypertarget{cite\the\value{instcount}}{%
    \iffieldundef{shorthand}
      {\ifciteseen
         {\ifciteibid
            {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
            {\ifthenelse{\ifciteidem\AND\NOT\boolean{cbx:noidem}}
               {\usebibmacro{cite:idem}%
                \usebibmacro{cite:title}}
               {\ifnameundef{labelname}
                  {\usebibmacro{cite:title}}
                  {\usebibmacro{cite:name}%
                   \ifopcit
                     {\ifloccit
                {\usebibmacro{cite:loccit}}
                {\usebibmacro{cite:opcit}}}
                     {\usebibmacro{cite:title}}}}}%
          \usebibmacro{cite:save}}
         {\usebibmacro{cite:full}%
       \usebibmacro{cite:save}}}
      {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}
```

Where we always give the shorthand the first shot (and not the full citation). Effectively we exchange the order of the check for `shorthand` and `\ifciteseen`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad1]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \bibhypertarget{cite\the\value{instcount}}{%
    \iffieldundef{shorthand}
      {\ifciteseen
         {\ifciteibid
            {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
            {\ifthenelse{\ifciteidem\AND\NOT\boolean{cbx:noidem}}
               {\usebibmacro{cite:idem}%
                \usebibmacro{cite:title}}
               {\ifnameundef{labelname}
                  {\usebibmacro{cite:title}}
                  {\usebibmacro{cite:name}%
                   \ifopcit
                     {\ifloccit
                {\usebibmacro{cite:loccit}}
                {\usebibmacro{cite:opcit}}}
                     {\usebibmacro{cite:title}}}}}%
          \usebibmacro{cite:save}}
         {\usebibmacro{cite:full}%
       \usebibmacro{cite:save}}}
      {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Some text.\autocite{kant:kpv}

Some text.\autocite{kant:kpv}

Some text.\autocite{worman}

Some text.\autocite{worman}

\printshorthands
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That's fantastic. A follow-up on that, is it possible to make the shorthands behave like the other posts, e.g. also print like ibid/idem etcetera? Now the shorthand is always printed out. This would be of interest, also without the macro above, e.g. also when the full title is printed the first time.

Comment: @johlie Normally it is preferred to ask follow-up questions in a new questions (referring back to the old one if necessary to give context). You would need to be a bit more precise about what tracker features you want, the only one I can think about is "ibid.", "idem" does not make sense: the author is not mentioned after all, (OK you could have "op cit.", but that doesn't convince me).