# Always use shorthand in biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex-chicago

I've been informed by my publisher that if I'm using a shorthand for a work, I should use it for every citation, including the first one. (Obviously, the full reference will appear in the list of shorthands and in the bibliography.) The closest I've seen to this question is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73913/how-can-i-use-shorthands-in-citations-from-the-first-time-with-biblatex), but the solution for `biblatex` (verbose) of course doesn't work with `biblatex-chicago`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[notes,shorthandibid,backend=biber,addendum=false,sorting=nyt,giveninits=true,useprefix=false,shorthandfull]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{jobname.bib}
@book{lastname98,
author = {Firstname Lastname},
title = {A Book},
shorthand = {Book},
date = {1898},
address = {City},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\printshorthands

Have a sentence.\autocite{lastname98}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one actually is in the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/doc/biblatex-chicago.pdf) (p137):

> User laudecir requested a way to present a shorthand even in the
>   first citation of a given work. The new `shorthandfirst` option in the
>   notes & bibliography style can be set to `true` either in the preamble
>   or in individual entries, and should make this functionality simpler
>   to activate than the `\shorthandcite` command.

And indeed `\usepackage[notes,shorthandibid,backend=biber,addendum=false,sorting=nyt,giveninits=true,useprefix=false,shorthandfull,shorthandfirst]{biblatex-chicago}` results in: [image]

Comment: Oops, hm, yeah, I might be looking at an out-of-date version of the manual--mine doesn't have that many pages! I shall download a new one, so thanks very much for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: Haha I had the same question and the same problem. Had to download the newest manual.